# converting jQuery to useEffect

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

is there anyway to convert jQuery to useEffect ? or to make this pice of code work in UseEffect

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').slider({
            indicators: false,
            height: 1000,
            transition: 500,
            interval: 6000
        });
    });
```

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using server side rendering, ReactDOM already works when the document is ready. Not only that, but since React components use a virtual DOM, jQuery can't tell on its own when they mount.

You should instead wrap the handler in a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array, like this:

```js
function Component(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    $('.slider').slider({
      // ...
    })
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```

An even better solution would be to find a React library on npm that does the same thing. Not only would it work better, but you won't be dependent on jQuery, which IMO React makes obsolete.

Comment: The $ seems to be undefined in useEffect now

Comment: @shlomominkowicz If you're using node modules, you have to `import $ from 'jquery'` before you can call it.